# How to echo text to cell, based on the value of another cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code, showing me raw data from a MySQL database in a table.
I want to add some text to one of the existing cells, depending on a value in another column which is not displayed in the table.
My code looks like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo '<tr class="lokbes">';
    echo "<td class='blaa'>" . $row['Navn'] . "</td>"; // I want the extra text here.
    echo "<td>" . $row['Stilling'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Institution'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='mailto:$row[Email]'>" . $row['Email'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Mobiltelefon'] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

This outputs a table consisting of Name, job, workplace etc.
In the cell displaying the name, I  would like to add some text if a column in my MySQL DB has the value 1 in the row.

What to do? I've tried using if, as seen below - but that doesn't seem to work.

```
echo "<td class='blaa'>" . $row['Navn'] . 
if ($row['Formand'] == 1) {
    echo "(Formand)";
} "</td>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do multiple echos :

```
echo "<td class='blaa'>" . $row['Navn']; 

if ($row['Formand'] == 1) {
    echo "(Formand)";
} 

echo "</td>";
```

Or, with ternary operator :

```
echo "<td class='blaa'>" . $row['Navn'] . ($row['Formand'] == 1 ? "(Formand)" : "") . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

update like this.

```
echo "<td class='blaa'>" . $row['Navn'];
if ($row['Formand'] == 1) {
    echo " (Formand)";
}
echo "</td>";
```

or you can use short PHP tag in HTML code.

```
?>
<td class="blaa">
    <?php echo $row['Navn']?><?php echo ($row['Formand'] == 1)?' (Formand)':'';?>
</td>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
echo '<tr class="lokbes">';
echo "<td class='blaa'>" . $row['Navn']." ".($row['Formand'] == 1 ? "(Formand)" : ""). "</td>"; // I want the extra text here.
echo "<td>" . $row['Stilling'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Institution'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='mailto:$row[Email]'>" . $row['Email'] . "</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Mobiltelefon'] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```